Hermitian vector bundle with a compatible connection
Given a hermitian vector bundle $(E,h)$ with a compatible connection $\nabla=\nabla^{1,0}+\nabla^{0,1}$, the compatibility states that for sections $s,u$ $$dh(s,u)=h(\nabla s,u)+h(s,\nabla u).$$ If we split $\nabla$ into the parts $\nabla^{1,0}$ and $\nabla^{0,1}$ we get $$dh(s,u)=\partial h(s,u)+\bar{\partial}h(s,u)=h(\nabla^{1,0}s,u)+h(\nabla^{0,1}s,u)+h(s,\nabla^{1,0}u)+h(s,\nabla^{0,1}u).$$
Do we have $$\bar{\partial}h(s,u)=h(\nabla^{0,1}s,u)+h(s,\nabla^{1,0}u)?$$
I think that this should be some kind of an type check, but I'm not sure about why the term $h(s,\nabla^{1,0}u)$ would be a $(0,1)$-form.

Because $h$ is conjugate-linear in the second slot.
